# Can we upload media files using URL in MediaFileUpload?

Tags: python-3.x, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Basically all I want to know is, I am working on **Youtube API** to upload videos on my channel. Whenever I try to upload video from my local file, it works without any issue. But if I want to upload some videos which are already hosted on **S3**, it gives me error related to OS i.e. **OSError: File not found at that location.**

So is there any way to **upload video using youtube API from already hosted URLs** ?

P.S. I am following the documentation of youtube API and using **MediaFileUpload** to upload the video files.

**Edit 1:** I tried a minor hack around this particular issue and works fine for me. Just leaving it here for future developers.

```
import requests
from six import BytesIO

url = "" # The video url you want to upload (I use S3 urls, not sure if it will work with youtube urls)

res = requests.get(url)
file = BytesIO(res.content)

media = MediaIoBaseUpload(file, mimetype="application/octet-stream")
```

Comment: The answer to your question is negative: your video file must come from local storage on your computer. The YouTube Data API does not offer the feature of uploading videos from remote locations.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and what @stvar said.

Comment: But, depending on the kind of hosted environment you have, you could well be implementing a bridge between the remote storage and the YouTube's endpoint via your computer by modifying the time-tested chunk-based resumable uploading procedure implemented by Google: [`upload_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py).